# Loadrunner has recorded "toolbarqueries.clients.google.com/tbproxy/af/query" can I disregard it?

Tags: loadrunner

I just recorded a script and found a number of web_custom_requests for "toolbarqueries.clients.google.com/tbproxy/af/query" I'm not sure what this is, I'm pretty sure Its nothing to do with what I want to record - so I'm commenting it out

Does anyone know what this is, or if its important?

NB: everything I'm recording is taking place internal to my organisation, there is no external traffic or web service calls - which is why I don't think I need this

I'm also seeing web_custom_requests  for googlesafebrowsing, I've commented these as well ?

Answer (score 0):

This probably means you have the Google toolbar installed on the browser you used to make your recording. Add on toolbars like this sort of 'piggyback' onto all the calls you make through the browser. You can either remove them from your script or uninstall the toolbar and re-record your script.

Comment: I'm recording with chrome.

Comment: Since Chrome is a Google product I assume then that the features in the Google toolbar are probably baked in to Chrome by default. Browsing information and search information from the user using Chrome are probably posted back to Google continuously and by recording using Chrome you are picking up that traffic in your script. If this is a concern you can either comment/delete these calls from the script, check Chrome for settings to disable that network traffic or record with a different browser.

Comment: That feeling when you discover the ugly truth about Chrome sending stuff to Google without you knowing.

Answer (score 0):

That address is part of autofill [chromium's form fill system](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/components/autofill/core/browser/autofill_download_manager.cc&q=tbproxy&sq=package:chromium&l=48).

A little more info here:
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142893?p=settings_autofill

Comment: Thanks, thats good to know- Reminder to self "Turn off autofill before recording!" Autofill is turned on by default. Follow the steps below to turn it off.
1. Click the Chrome menu  on the browser toolbar.
2. Select Settings.
3. Click Show advanced settings and find the "Passwords and forms" section.
4. Deselect the "Enable Autofill to fill out web forms in a single click" checkbox